# jcarousel thumbnail scrolling

Tags: scrollbar, jcarousel

I have a slideshow with scrolling thumbnails that was created using jCarousel. The thumbnails scroll downwards (forward) as expected. But scrolling backwards has a quirk that I cannot find a solution to. When the last thumbnail has been selected, the scrollbar will only scroll backwards by 8 thumbnails when in reality there are 22. I have tried playing around with the wrap, scroll, itemFallbackDimension & initCallback parameters without any change in the backwards (or in this case, upwards) scroll.

The files are here: http://ers-dev.com/Novartis/Flashcards/Clinical_Trials/index.html. But hurry and take a look, because I will have to take them down next week.

Comment: Someone pointed me to the 'scrollIntoView' function. The fact that I have an active thumbnail screws with the ability of the thumbnail slides to know how to get back to the beginning.

             item
                .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                    carouselNavigation.jcarousel('scrollIntoView', this);
                    item.addClass('active');
                })
                .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                    item.removeClass('active');
                })

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to have a scrollbar at all. That simply confuses the app because it loses its place. The solution is to use forward and back buttons. this way the carousel iterates through the slides one by one and it can keep track of where it is. 
There are built in classes to take care of this. .connected-carousels .prev-navigation and
.connected-carousels .next-navigation